# Django with apache-cassandra database with pycharm

Tags: python, django, cassandra

I am trying to create message app with a database model using Django framework using pycharm with apache-cassandra as a database. When I try to run

```
python manage.py migrate
```

in the terminal I get the following error,

> TypeError: Unknown option(s) for sync_cassandra command: app_label, check_unapplied, fake, fake_initial, interactive, migration_name, plan, run_syncdb. Valid options are: database, force_color, help, no_color, pythonpath, settings, skip_checks, stderr, stdout, traceback, verbosity, version.

My setting.py

```
"""
Django settings for DjangoProject project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""
import os
from pathlib import Path
from cassandra import ConsistencyLevel

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
from cassandra.cqlengine.connection import session

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parent.parent

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 's6+mmj8j^9qe+jy&=@^2i!cao!fnxeicaa24c^@se8n@o88t&r'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'posts.apps.PostsConfig',
]
INSTALLED_APPS = ['django_cassandra_engine'] + INSTALLED_APPS

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'DjangoProject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'DjangoProject.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases


DATABASES = {
    'sqlite': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    },
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_cassandra_engine',
        'NAME': 'my_keyspace',
        'TEST_NAME': 'MasterTable',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'replication': {
                'strategy_class': 'SimpleStrategy',
                'replication_factor': 1
            },
            'connection': {
                'consistency': ConsistencyLevel.SERIAL,
                'retry_connect': True
                # + All connection options for cassandra.cluster.Cluster()
            },
            'session': {
                'default_timeout': 10,
                'default_fetch_size': 10000
                # + All options for cassandra.cluster.Session()
            }
        }
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

However when I do a migration using the sqlite3, I don't have any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you've already figured it out.

The answer is that Cassandra does not have to migrate, but sync_cassandra.

Try:
python manage.py sync_cassandra